# Правильно ли составлено предложение? Нет ли стилистической ошибки?

Tags: стилистическая-сочетаемость

Обращение к главе о предоставлении дополнительных мер поддержки ЭКОНОМИКИ, в том числе ОТРАСЛЕЙ ЭКОНОМИКИ, в наибольшей степени пострадавших от коронавируса

Нет ли стилистической ошибки в заголовке письма?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки есть.

1. Проблема  сочетаемости слов.
   *Предоставить меры* (= кому-то) нельзя: меры *принимают*, осуществляют или представляют (к рассмотрению); предоставляют средства, помощь.
2. Пропущено "глава чего" (напр. администрации).
3. "*... экономики, в том числе отраслей экономики...*" Нельзя включить что-либо в *единственное* "число" (здесь: экономика). Это напоминает странное объявление на эскалаторе: "*если вы встретите пассажира с ограниченными возможностями, в том числе незрячег*о" (буквально пассажир один, но "в его числе" незрячий). В на "включая (отрасли)" или "в частности". Предлагаемый вариант:

> Обращение к главе *администрации* о *принятии* дополнительных мер
>   поддержки экономики, *в частности* отраслей,  наиболее пострадавших...

Пример с сохранением выражения "в том числе", связывающего предшествующее общее понятие (доп. мер**ы**) и входящие в него (в *число мер*) частности:

> Обращение к главе администрации о принятии дополнительных мер
>   поддержки экономики, в том числе мер поддержки наиболее пострадавших
>   отраслей...